# asyncio Transport does not close TCP connection

Tags: python, python-asyncio

So I'm having a bit of a problem with asyncio. Reference code is:

- [smtp.py](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd/blob/proxy-protocol/aiosmtpd/smtp.py)
- [test_proxyprotocol.py](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd/blob/proxy-protocol/aiosmtpd/tests/test_proxyprotocol.py)

In summary:

[Time out is set like so](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd/blob/3b3cabfdef1b5c3dcc79dc0b3649de4f6a92f9d2/aiosmtpd/smtp.py#L487-L492):

```py
    def _reset_timeout(self, duration=None):
        if self._timeout_handle is not None:
            self._timeout_handle.cancel()
        self._timeout_handle = self.loop.call_later(
            duration or self._timeout_duration, self._timeout_cb
        )
```

`self._timeout_cb` is like so:

```py
    def _timeout_cb(self):
        log.info('%r connection timeout', self.session.peer)
        self.transport.close()
```

[`_reset_timeout` is invoked in this part](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd/blob/3b3cabfdef1b5c3dcc79dc0b3649de4f6a92f9d2/aiosmtpd/smtp.py#L540-L550), like so:

```py
            self._reset_timeout(self._proxy_timeout)
```

The test is like so:

```py
class TestProxyProtocolV1Controller:
    def test_timeout(self, plain_controller):
        # The next line ensures that _proxy_timeout is set
        assert plain_controller.smtpd._proxy_timeout > 0.0
        prox_test = b"PROXY TCP4 255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 65535 65535\r\n"
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
            sock.connect(Global.SrvAddr)
            # The next line simulates timeout
            time.sleep(plain_controller.smtpd._proxy_timeout * 1.1)
            with pytest.raises(ConnectionAbortedError):
                sock.send(prox_test)
                _ = sock.recv(4096)
```

This test **works on Windows, but fails in Linux**. The failure is like so:

```
aiosmtpd/tests/test_proxyprotocol.py:632: in test_timeout
    _ = sock.recv(4096)
E   Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ConnectionAbortedError'>
```

If I remove the `pytest.raises` part in the test, it works in Linux ... but that means timeout is not ending the connection, and that is incorrect!

So, in essence, my thought is:

> `self.transport.close()` ended the TCP connection in Windows, but somehow kept TCP connection alive in Linux.

How do I make TCP connection ends on Linux? What else should I do besides `self.transport.close()`?

Comment: What's `ConnectionAbortedError`? If the server closes the transport, wouldn't the client simply see EOF?

Comment: @user4815162342 that's the exception I get on Windows when the last two lines of the test wasn't wrapped in `with pytest.raises`, so I just figure out that exception is the proper exception to raise when the connection gets half-closed by remote. Apparently, the behavior is different on Linux & FreeBSD...

Comment: It sounds like a windows-only thing, I've never heard of that exception. Checking for eof is perfectly fine there, it's not a hack or workaround by any means.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post my workaround that I implemented.

So, instead of mucking inside the server code, I edited the test case like so:

```py
class TestProxyProtocolV1Controller:
    def test_timeout(self, plain_controller):
        # The next line ensures that _proxy_timeout is set
        assert plain_controller.smtpd._proxy_timeout > 0.0
        prox_test = b"PROXY TCP4 255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 65535 65535\r\n"
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
            sock.connect(Global.SrvAddr)
            # The next line simulates timeout
            time.sleep(plain_controller.smtpd._proxy_timeout * 1.1)
            with pytest.raises(ConnectionAbortedError):
                sock.send(prox_test)
                resp = sock.recv(4096)
                if resp == b"":
                    raise ConnectionAbortedError
```

I'm totally not happy with this, so I'd appreciate any suggestions/corrections.

But in any case, the development can at least continue for the time being.